# Syntax error on token "QUOTE", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token

Tags: android

I've posted a bigger chunk of the code  below.  You can see that initially QUOTE was procedural- coded in place.  I'm trying to learn how to use declarative design so I want to do the same thing  but  by using resources.  It seems like I need to access the string.xml thru the @R.id tag and identify QUOTE with that string value.   But I don't know enough to negotiate this.  Any tips?  Thanks!

```
public class circle extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new GraphicsView(this));
}

static public class GraphicsView extends View {
    //private static final String QUOTE = "Happy Birthday to David.";

    private final String QUOTE = getString(R.string.quote);

    .....
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // Drawing commands go here
        canvas.drawPath(circle, cPaint);
        canvas.drawTextOnPath(QUOTE, circle, 0, 20, tPaint);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Basically I want to have the same text
>   but as a resource in strings.xml

At minimum, you heed a file named `res/values/strings.xml` with the following:

```
<resources>
  <string name="quote">Happy Birthday to David.</string>
</resources>
```

You then use `getString(R.string.quote)` to get at the string value in your Java code. Note that you already probably have a `res/values/strings.xml` file, created for you when the project was created, so just add the `<string>` element shown above alongside the other such elements in that file.

> Can someone please educate me a little
>   and recommend a good resource for
>   these type of questions? I'm using
>   HelloAndroid at the moment and I also
>   have "Beginning Android".

String resources are covered on pages 175-180 of *Beginning Android*. A current version of the sample project from that section [can be found here](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Resources/Strings/).

Comment: Ok, great!  Thanks for the time spent answering this- I really appreciate it!  I have created the string.xml file already, but using getString(R.string.quote) is where I  have the problem:
I get this error:
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getString(int) from the type Context

when I use this code:       private static final String QUOTE = getString(R.string.quote);
Thats why I tried the way I pasted in O.P.
So I guess that I'm instantiating a variable of the wrong type.
I haven't read the pages you recommend, so thats what I'm going to do right now.
Thanks again!
Dave.

Comment: @user356812 - `getString()` is an instance method, so you can't use it in a static initializer.

Comment: I still haven't found a solution- can anyone suggest a way of creating an instantiation of getString that can be used in a static initializer?  I've still got a lot of reading on net to do, but you could save me alot of time if you have a good explanation ;)

Comment: @user356812 - It is not possible to use `getString()` in a static initializer.

Comment: Ok, so I've been reading Beginning Android as suggested in the first answer.  It looks like I need to use String.format() so I'm going to play with that for a while.

Comment: no, this doesn't seem like the way.  I've sort of hit a wall on this one. I hate to leave it and just let it go, so any help would be appreciated

Comment: Ok, I think I've got it.  I just removed the static parameter from static public class GraphicsView.  N ow I can use getString().  But I wonder what consequences this could have in a more complex program?  Why was the class 'static' in  the first place?

Comment: @user356812 - in a `View`, use `getContext().getString()`, and you will need to call that in your constructor (after chaining to the superclass) or later. Otherwise, your `Context` will not be set up just yet. Bear in mind that creating custom `View` classes is a rather advanced technique that few developers ever use.

Comment: Ok, I'll give this a go.  I think that next I'm going to try and do the job of canvas.drawtext in layout.xml This may be easier/cleaner.